# Why doesn`t the finish statement execute after the yield key word executing in Tornado

Tags: tornado, yield

Here is my code, the question is:
the console **outputs** `"before, {"result" : "-1", "msg" : "Server error"}"`,
but it **doesn't output** `"after, {"result" : "-1", "msg" : "Server error"}"`,
it **doesn't execute** `self.finish(res)` the statement.

Anyone konws the reason? I wanna make `self.finish(res)` to execute. Please help me!

```
def get(self, param):
    try:
        do_something()
    except:
        res = '{"result" : "-1", "msg" : "Server error"}'
        logger.error('%s' % traceback.format_exc())
        print("before, %s" % res)
        yield tornado.gen.Task(self.captureException, exc_info=True)
        print("after, %s" % res)
    finally:
        do_something()
    self.finish(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `yield gen.Task()` you need to add asnyc decorators to your method:

```
from tornado import gen, web

@web.asynchronous
@gen.engine
def get(self, param):
    # your get method
```

Comment: I do add the following decorators: AT tornado.web.asynchronous and AT tornado.gen.engine

Comment: @AuroraWu and what about the captureException method? Does the callback method gets called at all possible exit points?

Comment: I know the reason, there is something wrong with my sentry server. And thanks @skazhy